# Pythonで3次元のlistをすべてtupleへ変換したい

Tags: python, python3

下記のように3次元のlistをtupleへ変換させたいのですがどうすれば良いのでしょうか。

```
obj1 = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
obj2 = (((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((5, 6), (7, 8)))
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
obj2 = tuple(map(lambda i: tuple(map(tuple, i)), obj1))
print(obj2)

# (((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((5, 6), (7, 8)))
```